# browser close event not page refresh/reload event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to detect the browser close event only not page refresh/reload event

I have tried this , but in both condition its working

```
    $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){

        });

 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

        }
$(window).unload(function() {  

});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific method for capturing browser `Close Event`.

You can only capture on `unload` of the current page.

Which also works when you try to `refresh` or `reload` the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with setting some value that checks if page was allready loaded and only then trigger onbeforeunload.

I was using something similar:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            if(is_form_dirty())
                return '<@msg "elections.general.modal.confirm.changes.text" />';
        }
```

Setting should be "session" based - so if possible use localstorage or just plain old cookies

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate event for reload or close. Browser fires the same bodyunload event for either of the case.

If you have to detect the close desparately, you can do by checking the coordinates from window.event.clientX and window.event.clientY. But this is the last thing you would want to do.

If you are using IE only, you can implement BHO that might detect the browser close explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

i did it like that;

```
    <script>

var mie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;

if (!mie) {
     document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
     document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
}

document.onmousemove = function (e) {mousePos(e);};
document.onmousedown = function (e) {mouseClicked();};

var mouseClick;
var keyClicked;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

function mousePos (e) {
    if (!mie) {
        mouseX = e.pageX; 
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    }
    else {
        mouseX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
        mouseY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }

    document.show.mouseXField.value = mouseX;
    document.show.mouseYField.value = mouseY;

    return true;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function (e)
        {
            e = e || window.event;
            var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
            if (y <= 0){    

            }
            else {
                if(document.show.mouseYField.value < 30) {
                    return 'Do you want to exit?';
                }
            }
          }
</script>

<form name ="show" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" name="mouseXField" value="0" size="6">Mouse X Position<br>
        <input type="text" name="mouseYField" value="0" size="6">Mouse Y Position<br>
</form>
```