# How to trigger only browser tab close event?

Tags: javascript

I want to clear localstorage data only on browser tab close. When i open new tab the localstorage should be set again. I tried with unload,beforeunload events they are working. but on refresh of browser also it's clearing localstorage. Can anyone suggest for only browser close event

```
localStorage.setItem("DISPLAY_MODAL", "1");
 window.addEventListener('unload',(e)=>{
     console.log(e);
     // Clear the local storage
    window.localStorage.clear()
 })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371257/browser-close-event-not-page-refresh-reload-event

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to use `sessionStorage` to begin with?